# Where can I place my game logic?

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I face a problem on how to maintain the life cycle of a game logic. I define a game logic in a `Fragment`. When I switch game fragment to other fragment like setting fragment, the fragment is released and the game logic is also released.

How do I maintain the game logic?

Answer (score 0):

Try using inner fragmnets..That is, Have a Parent fragment and than child fragment..and make your setting fragement visible and hide according to your need..